# how to Create Multi Head Convolutional layers merging as Temporal dimension in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, time-series

I want to implement a time-series prediction model which has a window of non-image matrixes as input , each matrix to be processed by a `Conv2d` layer at the first layer and then the output of this conv layers merged as time dimension to be passed to a recurrent layer like `LSTM`,

one way is to use **Time-Distribution technique**  but `TimeDistributed layer` apply the same layer to several inputs. And it produce one output per input to get the result in time, the Time-Distribution technique will share the same weights among all convolution heads which is not what I want, for example If you injects 5 Matrixes, the weights are not tweaked 5 times, but only once, and distributed to every blocks defined in the current Time Distributed layer. how can I avoid this and have independent Convolutional heads with outputs merging as time dimension for the next layer?

I have tried to implement it as following

```
    Matrix_Dimention=20;
    Input_Window=4;
    Input_Matrixes=[]
    ConvLayers=[]
    for i in range(0 , Input_Window):
            Inp_Matrix=layers.Input(shape=(Matrix_Dimention,Matrix_Dimention,1));
            Input_Matrixes.append(Inp_Matrix);
            conv=layers.Conv2D(64, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=(Matrix_Dimention,Matrix_Dimention,1))(Inp_Matrix)
            ConvLayers.append(conv);
            
    #Temporal Concatenation

    Spatial_Layers_Concate = layers.Concatenate(ConvLayers); # this causes error : Inputs to a layer should be tensors
    
    #Temporal Component

    LSTM_Layer=layers.LSTM(activation='relu',return_sequences=False)(Spatial_Layers_Concate )

    Model = keras.Model(Input_Matrixes, LSTM_Layer)
    Model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError)
```

it would be great if you provide your answer by correcting my implementation or provide your own if there is a better way to form this idea , tnx.

Comment: the cause of the error is because you call the Concatenate layer wrongly (it should be layers.Concatenate()(ConvLayers) ). However, Spatial_Layers_Concate produces a 4D tensor which is incompatible with LSTM, which accepts 3D input